# unix join separator char

Tags: csv, unix, join

Sorry for the maybe trivial question.

I fought a bit with the unix *join* command, trying to get tabs instead of whitespaces as the default separators. -t is the argument, but these don't work (ubuntu 9.10 64 bit 2.6.31-14, GNU coreutils version 7.4)

```
join file1 file2 -t"\t"
join file1 file2 -t="\t"
join file1 file2 -t="\\t"
join file1 file2 -t $"\t"
```

Et cetera. Of course, I can always use some inelegant solution like

```
join file1 file2 > output
sed "s/ /\t/g" output
```

But I wanted to look smart :-) Moreover, if there's a -t argument, it must work.

Comment: when use -t, as stated in man page, it says "Use character CHAR as the input and output field separator." when both your files have same terminator, then it works.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think it takes a variable generated on-the-fly

Try

```
join file1 file12 -t $'\t'
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know the `$'...'` syntax before.

Comment: The `$'...'`  syntax is [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Answer (score 6):

You can enter tab by pressing CTRL+v Tab

```
join -t '<CTRL+v><Tab>' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
join -t "`echo '\t'`" file1 file2
```

ps: on my machine, Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga), the command `join -t $'\t' file1 file2` returns "Illegal variable name".

Comment: Thanks for adding a distro-specific solution

Comment: That it does not work on Fedora 23, it outpus nothing.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate trick that seems to work is to enclose the -t option in quotes with the literal tab character.  This looks like:

```
join '-t    ' ...
```

with a variable space between the t and the closing quote (since it's a tab).

Typed, it's:

```
join<Spc>'-t<Ctrl-v><Tab>' ...
```

Answer (score 2):

man join says, that the options have to come in front of the filenames. Have you tried

```
join -t "\t" file1 file2
```

?

**Edit:** Reflecting Tonio's answer, the correct line would read

```
join -t $'\t' file1 file2
```

Comment: Yep, doesn't work.
It gives the error:
join: multi-character tab `\\t'

Comment: Remove the quotes? At least the error message disappears on my terminal.

Comment: I agree, error disappears, but the output is wrongly empty like this :-/

Comment: Worth noting that `$'\t'` is a bashism and won't work in all shells.

Answer (score 1):

Other way is:

> join -t "`echo -e "\t"`" file1 file2`

or in a more bash-fashion:

> join -t "$(echo -e "\t")" file1 file