# Rearrange columns using cut

Tags: shell, csv, cut

I am having a file in the following format

```
Column1    Column2
str1       1
str2       2
str3       3
```

I want the columns to be rearranged. I tried below command

> cut -f2,1 file.txt

The command doesn't reorder the columns. Any idea why its not working?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

For the `cut(1)` man page:

> Use one, and only one of -b, -c or -f.  Each LIST is  made  up  of 
>   one
>          range,  or  many ranges separated by commas.  Selected input is written
>          in the same order that it is read, and is written exactly  once.

It reaches field 1 first, so that is printed, followed by field 2.

Use `awk` instead:

```
awk '{ print $2 " " $1}' file.txt
```

Comment: It's too bad `cut` doesn't support this intuitive re-ordering command. Anyway, another tip: you can use `awk`'s `-FS` and `-OFS` options to use custom input and output field separators (like `-d` and `--output-delimiter` for `cut`).

Comment: Sorry, `FS` is an option, `OFS` is a variable.

e.g. `awk -v OFS=";" -F"\t" '{print $2,$1}'`

Comment: Note to Windows users of Git Bash: if you have weird output from the command above, looking like columns overriding each other, the carriage return is to blame. Change EOL in your file from CRLF to LF.

Comment: Alternatively if you don't want to change the input file, you can pipe it through `| sed 's/\r//' | ` before piping to `awk`

Comment: This one is very simple but might be useful for some, simply replace space with \t for reordering by tabs, and in case you want more columns, you can do it as for example `awk '{print $4 "\t" $2 "\t" $6 "\t" $7}' file`

Comment: So the reason it doesn't work is that `cut` can't reorder. It should just say that in the manual

Answer (score 77):

You may also combine `cut` and `paste`:

```
paste <(cut -f2 file.txt) <(cut -f1 file.txt)
```

via comments: It's possible to avoid process substitution and remove one instance of cut by doing:

```
paste file.txt file.txt | cut -f2,3
```

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as "cleverly", but: f=file.txt paste <(cut -f2 $f) <(cut -f1 $f).  Also, I note that this method is the easiest when you have lots of columns and want to move around large blocks of them.

Comment: doesn't work with cells of variable lengths in same column

Comment: @kraymer What do you mean?  `cut` works fine for variable-length columns as long as you have a unique column separator.

Comment: To eliminate the redundant file you could probably use tee:

Comment: worked like a charm !! @JJW5432 can you please provide an edit or an answer on how to avoid redundant file using tee..that will be helpful too..

Comment: Sorry I commented prematurely: I couldn't figure out how to merge the output of the `cut`s with paste. I think you need to use named papes or coprocesses or something that's a lot more trouble than it's worth, unless for some reason you really don't want to store it in a file.

Comment: It's possible to avoid *`bash`isms* and remove one instance of `cut` by doing:   
`paste file.txt file.txt | cut -f2,3`

Comment: Note that the second solution would only work when your delimiter is the same as paste's default output delimiter `\t`, which was the delimiter in the question.

Comment: @agc: Great trick in a pinch, but this has just become my new gold standard for "accidental complexity"

Answer (score 9):

Using `join`:

```
join -t $'\t' -o 1.2,1.1 file.txt file.txt
```

---

Notes:

- `-t $'\t'` In *GNU* `join` the more intuitive `-t '\t'` *without* the `$` fails, (*coreutils* *v8.28* and earlier?); it's probably a bug that a workaround like `$` should be necessary.  See: [unix join separator char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722353/unix-join-separator-char).
- Even though there's just *one* file being worked on, `join` syntax requires *two* filenames.  Repeating the file name allows `join` to perform the desired action.
- For systems with low resources `join` offers a smaller footprint than some of the tools used in other answers:

  ```
   wc -c $(realpath `which cut join sed awk perl`) | head -n -1
     43224 /usr/bin/cut
     47320 /usr/bin/join
    109840 /bin/sed
    658072 /usr/bin/gawk
   2093624 /usr/bin/perl
  ```

Comment: To be fair if you wanted low footprint you could just write your own custom utility in C... all of the utilities listed except Perl are coreutils.

Answer (score 7):

using just the shell,

```
while read -r col1 col2
do
  echo $col2 $col1
done <"file"
```

Comment: This is very often inefficient.  Typically, you will find that the corresponding Awk script is a lot faster, for example.  You should also be careful to quote the values `"$col2"` and `"$col1"` -- there could be shell metacharacters or other shenanigans in the data.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Perl for that:

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[1] $F[0]\n"' < file.txt
```

- -e option means execute the command after it
- -n means read line by line (open the file, in this case STDOUT, and loop over lines)
- -a means split such lines to a vector called @F ("F" - like Field). Perl indexes vectors starting from 0 unlike cut which indexes fields starting form 1.
- You can add -F *pattern* (with no space between -F and *pattern*) to use *pattern* as a field separator when reading the file instead of the default whitespace

The advantage of running perl is that (if you know Perl) you can do much more computation on F than rearranging columns.

Comment: perlrun (1) claims -a implicitly sets -n but if I run without -n set, it doesn't seem to loop. odd.

Comment: What version? `perl -ae print` works as `cat` for me

Answer (score 3):

Just been working on something very similar, I am not an expert but I thought I would share the commands I have used. I had a multi column csv which I only required 4 columns out of and then I needed to reorder them.

My file was pipe '|' delimited but that can be swapped out.

```
LC_ALL=C cut -d$'|' -f1,2,3,8,10 ./file/location.txt | sed -E "s/(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)/\3\|\5\|\1\|\2\|\4/" > ./newcsv.csv
```

Admittedly it is really rough and ready but it can be tweaked to suit!

Comment: This does not answer the question posed.  In the spirit of stack overflow please commit the time to answer a problem before you post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, really helpful. Hope you enjoy your badge.,

Answer (score 3):

Just as an addition to answers that suggest to duplicate the columns and then to do `cut`. For duplication, `paste` etc. will work only for files, but not for streams. In that case, use `sed` instead.

`cat file.txt | sed s/'.*'/'&\t&'/ | cut -f2,3`

This works on both files and streams, and this is interesting if instead of just reading from a file with `cat`, you do something interesting *before* re-arranging the columns.

By comparison, the following does not work:

`cat file.txt | paste - - | cut -f2,3`

Here, the double stdin placeholder `paste` does not duplicate stdin, but reads the next line.

Comment: to clarify, with sed, `&` is used to print the matched text. so here we're printing matched text twice split by a tab character

Answer (score 1):

**Using sed**

Use `sed` with basic regular expression's nested subexpressions to capture and reorder the column content.  This approach is best suited when there are a limited number of cuts to reorder columns, as in this case.

The basic idea is to surround interesting portions of the search pattern with `\(` and `\)`, which can be played back in the replacement pattern with `\#` where `#` represents the sequential position of the subexpression in the search pattern.

For example:

```
$ echo "foo bar" | sed "s/\(foo\) \(bar\)/\2 \1/"
```

yields:

```
bar foo
```

Text outside a subexpression is scanned but not retained for playback in the replacement string.

Although the question did not discuss fixed width columns, we will discuss here as this is a worthy measure of any solution posed.  For simplicity let's assume the file is space delimited although the solution can be extended for other delimiters.

**Collapsing Spaces**

To illustrate the simplest usage, let's assume that multiple spaces can be collapsed into single spaces, and the the second column values are terminated with EOL (and not space padded).

File:

```
bash-3.2$ cat f
Column1    Column2
str1       1
str2       2
str3       3
bash-3.2$ od -a f
0000000    C   o   l   u   m   n   1  sp  sp  sp  sp   C   o   l   u   m
0000020    n   2  nl   s   t   r   1  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   1  nl
0000040    s   t   r   2  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   2  nl   s   t   r
0000060    3  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   3  nl 
0000072
```

Transform:

```
bash-3.2$ sed "s/\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)[ ]*/\2 \1/" f
Column2 Column1
1 str1
2 str2
3 str3
bash-3.2$ sed "s/\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)[ ]*/\2 \1/" f | od -a
0000000    C   o   l   u   m   n   2  sp   C   o   l   u   m   n   1  nl
0000020    1  sp   s   t   r   1  nl   2  sp   s   t   r   2  nl   3  sp
0000040    s   t   r   3  nl
0000045
```

**Preserving Column Widths**

Let's now extend the method to a file with constant width columns, while allowing columns to be of differing widths.

File:

```
bash-3.2$ cat f2
Column1    Column2
str1       1
str2       2
str3       3
bash-3.2$ od -a f2
0000000    C   o   l   u   m   n   1  sp  sp  sp  sp   C   o   l   u   m
0000020    n   2  nl   s   t   r   1  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   1  sp
0000040   sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  nl   s   t   r   2  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp
0000060   sp   2  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  nl   s   t   r   3  sp  sp  sp
0000100   sp  sp  sp  sp   3  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  nl
0000114
```

Transform:

```
bash-3.2$ sed "s/\([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\)/\3\4 \1\2/" f2
Column2 Column1
1       str1      
2       str2      
3       str3      
bash-3.2$ sed "s/\([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\)/\3\4 \1\2/" f2 | od -a
0000000    C   o   l   u   m   n   2  sp   C   o   l   u   m   n   1  sp
0000020   sp  sp  nl   1  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   s   t   r   1  sp
0000040   sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  nl   2  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   s   t
0000060    r   2  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  nl   3  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp
0000100   sp   s   t   r   3  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  nl 
0000114
```

Lastly although the question's example does not have strings of unequal length, this `sed` expression supports this case.

File:

```
bash-3.2$ cat f3
Column1    Column2
str1       1      
string2    2      
str3       3
```

Transform:

```
bash-3.2$ sed "s/\([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\)/\3\4 \1\2/" f3
Column2 Column1   
1       str1      
2       string2   
3       str3    
bash-3.2$ sed "s/\([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\)/\3\4 \1\2/" f3 | od -a
0000000    C   o   l   u   m   n   2  sp   C   o   l   u   m   n   1  sp
0000020   sp  sp  nl   1  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   s   t   r   1  sp
0000040   sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  nl   2  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   s   t
0000060    r   i   n   g   2  sp  sp  sp  nl   3  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp
0000100   sp   s   t   r   3  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  nl 
0000114
```

**Comparison to other methods of column reordering under shell**

- Surprisingly for a file manipulation tool, `awk` is not well-suited for cutting from a field to end of record.  In `sed` this can be accomplished using regular expressions, e.g. `\(xxx.*$\)` where `xxx` is the expression to match the column.
- Using `paste` and `cut` subshells gets tricky when implementing inside shell scripts.  Code that works from the commandline fails to parse when brought inside a shell script.  At least this was my experience (which drove me to this approach).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from @Met, also using Perl:
If the input and output are TAB-delimited:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join "\t", @F[1, 0]' in_file
```

If the input and output are whitespace-delimited:

```
perl -lane 'print join " ", @F[1, 0]' in_file
```

Here,
`-e` tells Perl to look for the code inline, rather than in a separate script file,
`-n` reads the input 1 line at a time,
`-l` removes the input record separator (`\n` on *NIX) after reading the line (similar to `chomp`), and add output record separator (`\n` on *NIX) to each `print`,
`-a` splits the input line on whitespace into array `@F`,
`-F'\t'` in combination with `-a` splits the input line on TABs, instead of whitespace into array `@F`.

`@F[1, 0]` is the array made up of the 2nd and 1st elements of array `@F`, in this order. Remember that arrays in Perl are zero-indexed, while fields in `cut` are 1-indexed. So fields in `@F[0, 1]` are the same fields as the ones in `cut -f1,2`.

Note that such notation enables more flexible manipulation of input than in some other answers posted above (which are fine for a simple task). For example:

```
# reverses the order of fields:
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join "\t", reverse @F' in_file

# prints last and first fields only:
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join "\t", @F[-1, 0]' in_file
```