# rearrange columns using awk or cut command

Tags: awk, cut

I have large file with 1000 columns. I want to rearrange so that last column should be the 3rd column. FOr this i have used,

```
cut -f1-2,1000,3- file > out.txt
```

But this does not change the order.

Could anyone help using cut or awk?

Also, I want to rearrange columns 10 and 11 as shown below:

Example:

```
1   10   11   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert the final column between the original 2nd and 3rd columns so the 3rd column becomes the 4th, or are you trying to replace the 3rd column? Provide some sample input and expected output (and, of course, using 5 or 6 columns, not 1000!).

Comment: yes im trying to insert between 2nd and 3rd not replacing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rearrange columns using cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129123/rearrange-columns-using-cut)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this awk one-liner:

```bash
awk '{$3=$NF OFS $3;$NF=""}7' file
```

this is moving the last col to the 3rd col. if you have 1000, then it does it with 1000th col.

**EDIT**

if the file is tab-delimited, you could try:

```bash
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{$3=$NF OFS $3;$NF=""}7' file
```

**EDIT2**

add an example:

```bash
kent$  seq 20|paste -s -d'\t'                              
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20

kent$  seq 20|paste -s -d'\t'|awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{$3=$NF OFS $3;$NF=""}7'
1   2   20  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
```

**EDIT3**

You didn't give any input example. so assume you don't have empty columns in original file. (no continuous multi-tabs):

```bash
kent$  seq 20|paste -s -d'\t'|awk -F'\t'  -v OFS="\t" '{$3=$10 FS $11 FS $3;$10=$11="";gsub(/\t+/,"\t")}7'
1       2       10      11      3       4       5       6       7       8       9       12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20
```

After all we could print those fields in a loop.

Comment: Thanks. the original file is tab separated and with this command the delimiter is changing. What should be done to retain tab as the delimiter.

Comment: thanks. but it is printing the last column twice. i.e. in the 3rd column and also in the last column. It is required only once

Comment: @user1779730 I cannot see it happen. check my EDIT2 with an example.

Comment: @user1779730 I don't get you. my command gives output in "EDIT2"

Comment: @user1779730 where is EDIT3??? what do you want? I didn't write `$1 $2 $3 $4...$20`. did you check the code in EDIT2? Your question is move last col to before the original 3rd col. my command (awk) does it, EDIT2 shows an example. what's your problem? if your requirement changes, edit your question. or create a new question.

Comment: @user1779730 I see. you edited my answer to add new requirement. don't do it. edit your question pls.

Comment: @user1779730 see EDIT3.

Comment: I notice you have a number after the bracket statement.  Would I be correct to assume that's a shorthand for "print $0" as the last command in the program?  Is there any significance to which number is used?

Comment: you are correct. a non-zero number will do awk's default action: `print` @JohnChesshir

Comment: this is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

I THINK what you want is:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$3=$NF OFS $3; sub(OFS "[^" OFS "]*$","")}1' file
```

This might also work for you depending on your awk version:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$3=$NF OFS $3; NF--}1' file
```

Without the part after the semi-colon you'll have trailing tabs in your output.

Comment: I think we need the `OFS` var. because without the `OFS` when we set `$3=xxx` and output the line, awk will use the default `OFS`(space). It will change the original file format. but OP didn't give an example output. .. btw, I like the `NF--` very clever. Master!

Answer (score 0):

Since many people are searching for this and even the best awk solution is not really pretty and easy to use I wanted to post my solution (mycut) written in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)

#example usage: cat file | mycut 3 2 1

columns = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
delimiter = "\t"

for line in sys.stdin:
    parts = line.split(delimiter)

    print("\t".join([parts[col] for col in columns]))
```

I think about adding the other features of cut like changing the delimiter and a feature to use a * to print the remaning columns. But then it will get an own page.

Answer (score 0):

A shell wrapper function for `awk`' that uses simpler syntax:

```bash
# Usage: rearrange int_n [int_o int_p ... ] < file
rearrange () 
{ 
    unset n;
    n="{ print ";
    while [ "$1" ]; do
        n="$n\$$1\" \" ";
        shift;
    done;
    n="$n }";
    awk "$n" | grep '\w'
}
```

Examples...

```bash
echo foo bar baz | rearrange 2 3 1
bar baz foo
```

Using `bash` brace expansion, `rearrange` first and last 5 items in descending order:

```bash
echo {1..1000}a | tr '\n' ' ' | rearrange {1000..995} {5..1}
1000a 999a 998a 997a 996a 995a 5a 4a 3a 2a 1a
```

Sorted 3-letter shells in */bin*:

```bash
ls -lLSr /bin/?sh | rearrange 5 9 
150792 /bin/csh 
154072 /bin/ash 
771552 /bin/zsh 
1554072 /bin/ksh
```