# *nix join(1) command and its output column order

Tags: unix

I have two files, `FL` and `FR`, and would like to select those rows in `FL` that match the join condition below. However [`join(1)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28Unix%29)'s output modifies the layout of `FL`. Is there a way to guarantee that the `join`'s output will have the same layout (e. g. column order) as `FL`?

```
 FL:
 a 1 1 u
 b 2 2 v
 c 3 3 w

 FR:
 2

 join -1 2 -2 1 FL FR
```

Output:

```
 2 b 2 v
```

and I would like

```
 b 2 2 v
```

or in other words, the exact row of `FL` that matches the join condition. In 'real life' the file `FL` has many columns, and `FR` has a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX specification for [join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) says:

> The output line by default shall consist of the join field, then the remaining fields from *file1*, then the remaining fields from *file2*. This format can be changed by using the `-o` option.

Thus, the order of the fields is specified, either explicitly via the `-o` option or implicitly as stated.

In your example, you would need to specify the `-o` option:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -o "1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4" FL FR
```

If you have many fields in `FL`, then you'll need to list them all — unless you can arrange the columns differently.  For example, you might post-process the output:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 FL FR | awk '{ t=$1;$1=$2;$2=t; print }'
```

Comment: Since there's really one column to relocate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922805/rearrange-columns-using-awk-or-cut-command suggests a few ideas to reposition the first column.

Comment: They're more or less equivalent to what I suggest.  The main difference is that the code there might actually preserve spacing between the columns more accurately, though there are caveats about that, and it probably isn't a major issue for you.