# cut -f command for selecting multiple fields

Tags: cut

I have a file with as below:

```
A,B
1,hi there
2, Heloo there
```

I am trying to print the B column first and then column A

```
cat file.txt | cut -d "," -f2,1
```

However, this does not work. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rearrange columns using cut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129123/rearrange-columns-using-cut). Just use `awk` instead --> `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {print $2, $1}' file`

Comment: yup..thanks mate..was checking if it can be resolverd with cut as I am having issues with awk..it outputs with non bailable error :(