# multiple positional parameter assignment for "cut" command

Tags: bash

First I would like to say thanks ahead of time to all of you, that I hope to be a part of some day.  So I have a file that is a list of lines that are 5 parameters long. Such as

```
Bob:Wilson:Nebraska:34:yes
```

I need to write a program in BASH that will allow me to view the standard out put horizontally and will allow me to call the lines of text in the file like

```
$sh filename.sh 1
```

```
Bob
Tom
Dave
etc..
```

or

```
$sh filename.sh 1 3 4 2
```

```
Bob:Nebraska:34:Wilson
Tom:Iowa:27:Anderson
etc..
```

What I have written so far is

```
cut -d : -f$1,$2,$3,$4,$5 somefile.txt | paste -s
```

The problem is if the user puts in less then 5 parameters after sh filename.sh I get an error code. The user is not required to put in 5 but can call up to 5.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F: -v c="$1 $2 $3 $4 $5" 'BEGIN {n=split(c,a," ")} 
                                     {for(i=1;i<n;i++) printf "%s", $a[i] FS; 
                                      printf "%s\n", $a[n]}' file
```

try and let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: I see the use of "awk" a lot to answer these question on this board (I have been creeping for a while) but we have yet to cover it in class so I not familiar with it enough to use it but thank you very much for your input!!  I am learning this on line and it leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

## Expand Only Existing Parameters

```
IFS=,
cut -d : -f"$*" somefile.txt
```

`$*` expands to `1st parameter` `$IFS` `2nd parameter` `$IFS` ... `$IFS` `last parameter`, that is `$1,$2` if two parameters were given, `$1,$2,$3` if three were given, and so on.

## Allow Rearranging

The command from above has a problem: `cut` cannot rearrange columns. `cut -f1,2` is equivalent to `cut -f2,1`. See [rearrange columns using cut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129123/6770384). Therefore we use `awk` instead.

If the parameters were `filename.sh 1 3 4 2`, then we would need the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '{ print $1, $3, $4, $2 }' somefile.txt
```

`-F` sets the field seperator for reading the file. `-v OFS=:` sets the field seperator of the output. `print $1, $3, ...` means »*print the first field, then the third, ...*«. Note that `'$1'` is *not* the first argument of your script, but a literal string that is interpreted by awk.

We use the same trick as before to build an `awk`-command from the given parameters.

```
IFS=,
awk -F: -v OFS=: "{ print ${*/#/$} }" somefile.txt
```

`${*/#/$}` prepends `$` to each parameter. The expansion will be `$` `1st parameter` `,` `$` `2nd parameter` `,` ... `,` `$` `last parameter`.

Comment: I forgot to add the ". Thanks

Comment: Your script doesn't give the requested output. When called `./script 1 3 4 2` it will output `Bob:Wilson:Nebraska:34` instead of `Bob:Nebraska:34:Wilson`.

Comment: `cut` cannot change the order of fields. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2129123/6770384). Since Grunt asked primarily about the parameters instead of the actual cutting I assumed that wasn't a problem for him/her. But you are right, I should fix this.

Comment: Thanks to inferno for letting me know that cut will not rearrange the order.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would always avoid text processing with shell scripts. There are better tools like `sed`, `awk` or `perl` to name a few. This is how I would do it in pure bash since that seems to be what you are looking for (*):

```
#!/bin/bash
#file: script.sh

for line in $(<somefile.txt); do
   array=( ${line//:/ } )
   counter=1
   for elem in $@; do
      echo -n "${array[$elem-1]}"
      [ $counter -ne $# ] && echo -n ":"
      ((counter++))
   done
   echo
done
```

(*): Don't be confused by the syntax highlighting, which recognizes everything after `$#` as a comment (gray text). It's all syntactically correct in the example script.

**Explanation:**

The script reads somefile.txt, splits each line at the `:` characters and stores the resulting fields/elements in the array `array`. Then it outputs the fields in the order specified by your script arguments (`$@`).

Here is the output, exactly how you want it:

```
$ ./script.sh 1
Bob
Tom

$ ./script.sh 1 3 4 2
Bob:Nebraska:34:Wilson
Tom:Iowa:27:Anderson
```

*Also note the following:*

In your example you possibly execute your script with the Bourne Shell (`sh`) and not `bash`. The script above however requires `bash` because it uses the [substring replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) feature.