# Replace a column in txt file with onother using java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the folowing txt file:

`COL1   COL2    Col3
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9`

And onother txt file:

```
COL1
11
44
77
```

What I want to do is to repalce the first column of the first txt file, with the first column of the second column.

Is there a fast way to do that using java, or I have to replace line by line?

Comment: You need to open the file. Read it in line by line. Replace the column you want replaced and then write out the new changed line to a new file. When you are done you can delete the original file but I wouldn't do that until you are sure the change was made correctly.

Comment: yep its line by line, but if time is what you are worried about, this process can be done in less than a sec for 1M lines or so.

Comment: Yes I have been thinking to do that, but I want to know if there is a simple and fast way to do that, because I have to read a voluminous txt file.

Comment: @nafas thanks for the information, I think that's it, there no other way.

Comment: For ways to do this without writing a new program, see also the answers in [Rearrange columns using cut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129123/rearrange-columns-using-cut).

Comment: @AndyThomas Thanks, I need to do it using java.