# More elegant way to change format of date without multiple variables and substrings

Tags: string, bash, unix

I'm manipulating a string representing a date formatted as YYYY/MM/DD into a date formatted as MM/DD/YYYY. I'm doing this by extracting the month, day, and year into three separate variables using the cut command, then concatenating them back together. Is there a more elegant way of achieving this same result without relying on so many variables and cutting up and reassembling the string?

Comment: `old_date='2019/12/31'` ; `new_date=${old_date:5:2}'/'${old_date:8:2}'/'${old_date:0:4}`; `echo ${new_date}` => `12/31/2019`; benefit = eliminates overhead of invoking subprocesses for `cut` operations

Comment: This question is closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129123/rearrange-columns-using-cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed`. In the search string use groups `(...)` to capture the parts, then, in the replace string address these groups using `\1`, `\2`, ... .

```
sed -E 's|(....)/(..)/(..)|\2/\3/\1|'
```

alternatively, use `awk`

```
awk -F/ '{print $2 "/" $3 "/" $1}'
```

If you want to convert the date inside the variable `$date` use

```
date=$(insertAnyCommandFromAbove <<< "$date")
```